# Send multiple parameters from ember component

Tags: ember.js

I want to send two parameters to an action in an Ember component. The [documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/) only suggests how to send one parameter eg as

```
{{#each todos as |todo|}}
    <p>{{todo.title}} {{confirm-button title="Delete" action="deleteTodo" param=todo}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

How do I send multiple params? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way you sent the first one:

```
{{confirm-button title="Delete" action="deleteTodo" param=todo param2=myOtherParam}}
```